# Regex: How to turn more words in the line as if they were seen in the mirror?

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

Mirrors Actually Flip the Letters in a Word? Or, how to turn more words in the line as if they were seen in the mirror?

For example:

`At the Olympics you run not only for yourself, but for all people.`

After using a regex formula, **the output should be**:

`Ta eht scipmylO uoy nur ton ylno rof flesruoy, tub rof lla elpoep.`

I made a regex formula, but is not working:

FIND: `([a-z])|([A-Z])\1\2`

REPLACE BY: `\2\1`

OR

FIND: `([^\s])|([^\s])`

REPLACE BY: `\2\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done with regex alone, you have to run a pythonSCript.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example reverseWord.py):

```python
import re

def reverseWord(match):
    str = match.group(1)
    return ''.join(reversed(str))

editor.rereplace('(\w+)', reverseWord)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> reverseWord)
- Done

[image]

Comment: thanks, works. But I must use the notepad++ Installed Version, not the Portable Version

Comment: @JustMe: I was answering the same thing ;)

Comment: something else. I update your code a little bit, as to work in normal Python IDLE. But seems that the Editor plugin of Notepad++ is not good for IDLE. Check here the script; https://pastebin.com/JgwsWYwA   And check here the error:  https://snipboard.io/ACThZu.jpg

Comment: @JustMe: PythonScript is specific to Notepad++ and cannot be used as standalone or in another editor.

Comment: I see, thanks @Toto

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for @Toto code, I find a Python code that works in any IDLE:

```
string = "Python guides is best"
word = string.split()
reverse_str = []
for i in word:
    reverse_str.append(i[::-1])
res = " ".join(reverse_str)
print("",res)

#Output: nohtyP sediug si tseb
```